# Understanding how exactly 'assert' works

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim, system-verilog-assertions

I am facing a puzzling behavior of Systemverilog 'assert' when trying to verify a flip-flop had sampled the input value on a rising edge. It seems that the assert will pass if I add an arbitrarily small delay AFTER the rising edge, but not right on it. However if I add an 'always' block that prints the value of the output at the rising edge time, it will show the correct value. BTW and 'if' comparison behaves like 'assert'. I am using Modelsim as my simulator. Below is my code with inline comments to illustrate the problem. Please also look at the image in the link for further illustration. [image: Modelsim Image]
Thanks.

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns


module example_t(input logic clk, input logic resetb, input logic selector, output logic result);

always_ff @ (posedge clk or ~resetb)
  if(~resetb)
    result <= 0;
  else
    result <= selector ?  1'b1  :  1'b0;
endmodule 


module tst();

logic clk;
logic resetb;
logic selector;
logic result;

example_t example(.clk(clk), .resetb(resetb), .selector(selector), .result(result));

//Simulate a clock 
always
  #10 clk = ~clk;
  
initial
 begin
    clk = 0;
    resetb = 0; //Reset
    selector = 0;
    
    #20
    @(posedge clk);
    resetb = 1;
    
    #20
    @(posedge clk);
    selector = 1;
    
    #20            //**At this time we are at 70ns**
    @(posedge clk); //**We are already at the posedge, but adding just in case**
    assert(result == 1'b1); //**This will fail, meaning result[enter image description here][1]==0 at 70ns**
    
 end
 
 always @ (result)
  begin
    $display("result=%h time=%t",result, $realtime); //**This will print the value at 70ns as 1**
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: FYI: `always_ff @ (posedge clk or ~resetb)` should be `always_ff @ (posedge clk or negedge resetb)`

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems in the code.

1. The problem is a race on the `selector` (and on `resetb`). You modify the signals  with **blocking** assignments at the same simulation cycle as you use them.  Depending on simulator or simulation conditions the update can happen before or after its use. As a result, synopsys and cadence have result ready at time 50, making assertion happy. On the other hand, mentor an aldera make result ready at 70 only and cause assertion failure at this time. You can avoid this issue and use nbas and make every compiler to have results ready at 70.
2. There is a slightly different source of race which involves the immeditate assertion in the initial block. The conditional expression in it will be executed as a part of the procedural block flow in active region, before non-blocking assignments. It still sees the old value of the *result* and is evaluated to false.

The way around it is to set 'selector' and `resetb` way before the posedge. The following will make everyone happy. The result will be ready at 50 and assertion at 70 will be happy as well.

```
initial
 begin
    clk = 0;
    resetb = 0; //Reset
    selector = 0;
    
    #15    
    resetb = 1; // set it before the next posedge
   
    @(posedge clk); // wait for posedge
   
    #10   
    selector = 1; // set it before the next edge
    
    #20            //**At this time we are at 70ns**
    @(posedge clk); //**We are already at the posedge, but adding just in case**
    assert(result == 1'b1) $info("Assertion is ok at %0t", $realtime); //**This will fail, meaning result[enter image description here][1]==0 at 70ns**
    
   #20 $finish;
 end
```

Comment: FYI, this is an _immediate_ assertion and there is no sampling of `result`; you would always get the _old_ value because of the NBA to it. Your comments about the testbench stimulus races are correct though.

Comment: @dave_59 yes, you are correct. there is a differecnt mechanism involved there. It yields the same results. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I used ~resetb and not (negedge resetb) since I wanted resetb to be an asynchronous reset signal. At the same time I do not want it to de-assert asynchronously hence I change it in sync with the clk. Therefore it made me somewhat uneasy to change it in the middle of a clk cycle like in your code. I tried the other suggestion - use NBAs in the testbentch. My understanding was that you mean assigning 1 to 'selector' at 50ns using the <= operator. That did not change the outcome.

Comment: Generally speaking, while doing testbentches with simulated "zero time" flip flops (no propagation delay simulated) I find it ackward to make my signals ready some arbitrary time before the rising edge. Perhaps it is my SW background that makes me uneasy :-)

Comment: I would expect that if zero propagation delay is simulated, and I am using SW-like pointers like @(posedge clk) as clues for the simulator that an assignment was done "epsilon time" before the rising edge, I will be able to build more "streamlined" testbentches where I dont have to sprinkle those small arbitrary delays everywhere. Is there a good way to re-write my code above such that those tiny "tehoretical delays" are taken care of by the complier/simulator?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) using `<=` does not change the outcome, but makes the assertion failure determenistic so, that it works the same across multiple compilers and conditions. In case of `=` it is non-determenistic. It is the same for **both** signals. 2) verilog describes behavior of hadware and delays in tb are normal. 3) @(posedge...) is not a pointer, it is an event contro. Verilog code is simulates in an *event-driven* fashion, both rtl and tb. *rising edge* is just another event among otheres, there is no 'epsilon time' before it. `<=` makes sure that the assighment happens *after* all events are done.